# I'm trying to save data from views

Tags: django

My forms.py file:

```
class RegisterForm(ModelForm):
    """This form lets people register as members."""

    help_string = "Please choose a password that is at 6 characters long,"\
        "and contains at least on speacial character or number"

    First_Name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    Last_Name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)  
    Username = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    Password = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    Confirm_Password = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    Email_Address = forms.EmailField()
    Address = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    def save(self, commit=True): 
        cd = self.cleaned_data
        u = User.objects.create_user(
            username=self.cleaned_data['Username'],
            email=self.cleaned_data['Email_Address'],
            password=self.cleaned_data['Password'],
            )
        u.is_staff = True
        u.save()
        u.First_Name = self.cleaned_data['First_Name']
        u.Last_Name = self.cleaned_data['Last_Name']
        m = self.instance
        m.user = u
        if not commit:
            return [m, u]
        u.save()
        m.save()
        return m
```

My views.py file:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                instance = form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/registered/')
            except:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/validation/')
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()

    return render_to_response(
        'homepage/register.html',     
        {'form':form,},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request),
        )
```

My register.html template:

```
<h4>Register</h4>
<form action="" method="POST">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" id="eric">
        <tr>
        <td>{{ form.as_table }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Create Account">
                <input type="Reset"  value="Clear"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

The thing what it does in views.py is skip the try block and execute the except.
What should I do or change?

Comment: please remove the try-except block it will tell you exactly what happen.

Comment: I am sure it will throw integrity database error if no syntax error occurs..

Comment: I did it, I also removed the return statement that the except block was returning, what it does now it throws InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.

Comment: Now it changed to IntegrityError: column username is not unique

Answer (score 0):

So, You are saving the data twice. And in your model definition username must be unique. So, throwing integrity error. You are saving data in

```
1.) Forms save
2.) again same data you are saving in Views.
```

My suggestion.

```
clean your data in the forms.
Remove save() from forms.
save form in views.


class RegisterForm(ModelForm):
        """This form lets people register as members."""

        help_string = "Please choose a password that is at 6 characters long,"\
            "and contains at least on speacial character or number"

        First_Name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
        Last_Name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)  
        Username = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
        Password = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
        Confirm_Password = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
        Email_Address = forms.EmailField()
        Address = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

        def clean_name(self,):
            username = self.cleaned_data['Username']
            return username

        def clean_email(self,):
            email = self.cleaned_data['Email_Address']
            param = {'email': email}
            if dbapi.get_user(**param):
                raise ValidationError('Email already registered')
            return email
        def clean_password(self,):
            // your logic here
```

In views.

**Not resembles your code**

**All values are dummy here You just fit according to your values**

**register_name should be the instance of your Form**

```
username = register_form.cleaned_data['username']
email = register_form.cleaned_data['email']
password = register_form.cleaned_data['password']
name = register_form.cleaned_data['name']
# Create a user obj                                                                                                                             
user_obj = create_user(username, email, password) // to create a user_obj
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#creating-users
user_obj.first_name = 'xxxxxxxxx'
user_obj.last_name = 'xxxxxxxxxx'
user_obj.save()
```

Ok. I am writting here a `create_user` method:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
def create_user(username, email, password):
    # This will return the user_obj
    return User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
```

Comment: Hi Tauquir, in views it throws NameError: global name register_form is not defined? Again this code in views do I apply it after the: if form.is_valid(). Thanks

Comment: The register_form error is sorted, the one that throws errror in views: user_dbapi is not defined, how should I defined it? Thanks

Comment: hey @smasher it is a dummy name. user_dbapi is py file from where it call a method create_user which will insert username, password & email in the database and it will return a user_obj. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#creating-users

Comment: Yes I did all bt throws InterfacaError: Error binding parameter 0 probably unsupported type.

Comment: somewhere in the code you are passing dictionary to get method. Is somewhere you are doing like Model.objects.get(here you are passing dict). Model is any of your models.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using ModelForm, I suggest you remove the 'except' in your registration function. It should look like this:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/registered/')

    else:
        form = RegisterForm()

    return render_to_response(
        'homepage/register.html',     
        {'form':form,},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request),
        )
```

The reason of removing the 'except' is that you are already using modelform and it provides you with form validations. You don't have to create a template telling the user that their input is invalid (that is if you are using /validation/ to tell the user that they have invalid input).